# Is it Dhruva padam or Dhruta padam in Dhyanam before Rudram?

Tags: scripture, sanskrit, yajur-veda, rudram

I've seen two versions of dhyanam before Rudram (Namakam).

> āpātāḷa-nabhaḥsthalānta-bhuvana-brahmāṇḍa-māvisphurat-
> jyotiḥ sphāṭika-liṅga-mauḷi-vilasat-pūrṇendu-vāntāmṛtaiḥ |

> astokāpluta-meka-mīśa-maniśaṃ rudrānu-vākāñjapan
> dhyāye-dīpsita-siddhaye **dhruvapadaṃ** vipro﻿‌உbhiṣiñce-ccivam ||

and this devanagari version

> आपातालनभःस्थलान्तभुवनब्रह्माण्डमाविस्फुर-
> ज्ज्योतिः स्फाटिकलिङ्गमौलिविलसत् पूर्णेन्दुवान्तामृतैः ।

> अस्तोकाप्लुतमेकमीशमनिशं रुद्रानुवाकाञ्जपन्
> ध्यायेदीप्सित सिद्धयेऽ**द्रुतपदं** विप्रोऽभिषिञ्चेच्छिवम् ॥

I also have a book with me in Telegu which had also printed **dhruva padam**. So which  one is the correct one?

So is it stable path or fast path?

Comment: Both are correct, Idk what you mean by stable path or fast path.

Comment: He translates Dhruva padam as stable path and Druta padam as fast path. @Proxy

Comment: !NOTE! Clicking on link will result in downloading the article. See [this](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/rudram_skt_accent.pdf)  Locate the foot note on page 6.

Comment: @Proxy Please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dhynam of Shri-Rudram Both,

> अस्तोकाप्लुतमेकमीशमनिशं रुद्रानुवाकाञ्जपन् ध्यायेदीप्सित सिद्धयेऽ**द्रुतपदं** विप्रोऽभिषिञ्चेच्छिवम् ॥

And

> अस्तोकाप्लुतमेकमीशमनिशं रुद्रानुवाकाञ्जपन् ध्यायेदीप्सित सिद्धयेऽ**ध्रुवपदं** विप्रोऽभिषिञ्चेच्छिवम् ॥

Are valid, I.e. **Both *Drut Padam* (द्रुतपदं) and *Druva Padam* (ध्रुवपदं) are valid**.

One can use [this](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/rudram_skt_accent.pdf) document of Shri-Rudram Chant from [Sanskrit Documents](https://sanskritdocuments.org/) to see this as well as other such variations.
*Note:clicking on the link would result into download*

*Druva padam* refers to the position like of the *Druva* (North star- the one that remains fixed) i.e. permanent or unchanging. While *Drut padam* meaning quickly.

<sub>Alternatively use [this](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/rudra.html) and locate the link to the article "Skt Dvng".</sub>